SSIS: Seeing complete warning message in pop-up bubble
How can I see the whole warning in an SSIS ETL package? In the screenshot you can see that SSIS cuts half of the message.


IIRC, it shows up in the "Error List" window when you double click it and press OK in the component's editor window, but disappears as soon as you save the project.

Oh, yeah. I forgot about this. As far as I can tell, this seems to be tied to package validation as well. Unfortunately, this is only done when the package is opened for the first time after a project is opened (provided you're not in offline mode) and there's no way to manually trigger that. Again, it disappears when you save. Yes, it's dumb.
